Stability Analysis of the Wave Equation using Crank-Nicolson Method - No Clear Time Step Restriction?
I am analyzing the stability of the following wave equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}.
$$
I applied the Crank-Nicolson method directly to the equation without any splitting:
$$
\frac{\phi_j^{n+1} - 2\phi_j^n + \phi_j^{n-1}}{\Delta t^2} = \frac{c^2}{2} \left( \frac{\partial^2 \phi_j^{n+1}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_j^n}{\partial x^2} \right).
$$
where the spatial derivative is discretized using the second-order central difference scheme.
To perform the stability analysis, I assumed a Fourier mode solution of the form:
$$
\phi_j^n = \sigma^n e^{i k x},
$$
where
σ is the amplification factor, and
k is the wavenumber.
Is the Crank-Nicolson method unconditionally stable for the wave equation?
If not, what is the appropriate stability condition or restriction on the time step Δt for this discretization scheme?
